# How to serialize ArrayList json

Tags: c#, json, arraylist

So this is my object class:

```
public class personSerialize
{
    public string[] name { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
};
```

And the object creation code is:

```
personSerialize personObject = new personSerialize()
{
    name = people, //'people' is an ArrayList BTW
    number = peopleNum
};
```

And it returns one error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'string[]'

I know '[]' isnt ArrayList but I have no idea what else to say. Thanks

Comment: try -> `name = (string[]) people.ToArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the error, you have to convert your `ArrayList` to an array like this:

```
name = (string[]) people.ToArray( typeof(string) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign `ArrayList` to the `String[]` array.
You need to fist convert your `ArrayList` into the `Array` and then cast the result into `string[]` array as `ArrayList` contains collection of `objects` not strings.

Try This:

```
name = (string[]) people.ToArray()
```

**Suggestion:**  we used to use `ArrayList` in olden days and it is not `type safe`  as its content only be know at runtime.

you you can use GenericCollections `(typesafe)` here to avoid the runtime exceptions.
you can import the Generic Collections using following Namespace

`using System.Collections.Generic;`

then you can use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

**Note:** you need to mention the type upfront before using the `List<T>`.so it is typesafe and avoid the runtime exceptions.

you can use List asbelow:

```
List<string> list=new List<string>();
list.Add("mystring1");
list.Add("mystring2");
list.Add("mystring3");
```